# Как заполнить с клавиатуры массив студентов и вывести их оценки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

мой код:

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, full_name="", group_number="", progress=[]):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.group_number = group_number
        self.progress = progress

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(("Студент: " + self.full_name + "  Группа: " + self.group_number))

    def addStu(self):
        print("Введите Фио: ")
        st.full_name = input()
        print("Введите номер группы: ")
        st.group_number = input()
        print("Введите последние 5 отценок : ")
        st.progress = []



st_size = 2
sz_ocenki = 5
students = []
for i in range(st_size):
    st = Student()
    st.addStu()
    for i in range(5):
        score = int(input())
        st.progress.append(score)
        # мне не понятно, как сохранять введенные данные 'score' , 
        # что б я в дальнейшем могу высчитать сумму и разделить на 
        # 5(кол-во оценок), тем самым получив средний балл (все это во float)
    students.append(st)
```

Я конкретный новичок и свою проблему я не могу нормально загуглить (сформулировать мысль для поисковика)

В классе STUDENT, содержатся следующие поля:

- фамилия и инициалы;
- номер группы;
- успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов).

Надо написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:

- ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив, состоящий из десяти экземпляров класса
  STUDENT (записи должны быть упорядочены по возрастанию среднего балла);
- вывод на экран фамилий и номеров групп для всех студентов, имеющих оценки 4 и 5
  (если таких студентов нет, вывести соответствующее сообщение).

Comment: вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Цикл надо было прописать в методе.
2. В методах не используйте посторонних переменных.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, full_name="", group_number="", progress=[]):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.group_number = group_number
        self.progress = progress

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(("Студент: " + self.full_name + "  Группа: " + self.group_number))

    def addStu(self):
        print("Введите Фио: ")
        self.full_name = input()
        print("Введите номер группы: ")
        self.group_number = input()
        print("Введите последние 5 отценок : ")
        self.progress = []
        for i in range(5):
            score = int(input())
            self.progress.append(score)
    def getMarks(self): # возвращает список оценок
        return self.progress
        


st_size = 2
sz_ocenki = 5
students = [] # список студентов
for i in range(st_size):
    st = Student()
    st.addStu()
    students.append(st); 
    
for student in students:
    print(student.getMarks())
```

Дальше сами, там уже легко.
P.S На питоне не писал очень давно уже, так что не судите строго.